# Shutter - Wait until menu dissapear

Tags: 13.10, shutter

I'm using Gnome Shell and I have difficulties with Shutter. When I want to take a screenshot, I open menu in upper panel, but I also get that menu in my screenshot.

Is there any chance that Shutter waits until menu dissapears, and then make a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the menu, use the shutter toolbar buttons - Selection, Desktop, Window.

Check out image below:

[image]